# Can somebody please explain the size limit of a document in MongoDB? It says there is a 16MB limit per document but what does it mean?

Tags: mongodb, web, web-applications, nosql, bson

I have about 3 collections and each don’t even have a lot of data. Each of them have about 50 objects/items that each contain around 200 characters but the whole collection (one collection) is taking up ≈270KB of space (which is a lot). I don’t understand why it is doing that.

So going back to the question, do those collections each have a limit of 16mb or is it the entire database? Please help. Thank you.

Comment: 16mb is the max size of one object

Comment: Like a single object inside a collection? For example a user’s biography? @ashenmadusanka

Comment: See [MongoDB Document Limitations](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-limitations)

Comment: yes exactly. it's in the MongoDB limitations page https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here are some examples:

```
Object.bsonsize({ a: null }) => 8
Object.bsonsize({}) => 5
Object.bsonsize({ _id: ObjectId() }) => 22

Object.bsonsize({a: "fo"}) => 15
Object.bsonsize({a: "foo"}) => 16
Object.bsonsize({ab: "fo"}) => 16
```

5 Bytes seems to be smallest possible size.

You can retrieve the BSON size of your documents with this aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{ $project: { size: { $bsonSize: "$$ROOT" } } }])
```

The max size of **a document** is 16 MiByte, which is a hard-code limit. Each document has the `_id` field with typically an ObjectId value, thus the minimum size of a document is 22 Byte.

According to [MongoDB: The Definitive Guide](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mongodb-the-definitive/9781491954454/) the entire text of *"War and Peace"* is just 3.14MB, so 16MiB is quite a lot.